# Cannot resize partition on HFS+ drive using disk utility

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I purchased a 2 TB SSD and cloned everything from my old 1 TB hard drive. But now I keep getting "Your startup disk is full" errors. So I removed the hard drive and connected it to my other computer. I'm trying to resize the partition, but it shows there is no room.

Screenshot of Partition Resizing in Disk Utility:

[image]

[image: Screenshot of Info]

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Well                    749.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
```

Comment: Probably because your recovery partition starts immediately after it.  You will need to *move* that over so the free space follows the partition you want to grow.

Comment: How do I move it over?

Comment: If the mac disk utility can't do it you can use a gparted live cd.